# Django. Где следует валидировать данные?

Tags: python, django

Пишу на Django довольно давно, но возник такой философский вопрос.

Я сторонник того, чтобы всевозможные проверки на корректность данных проводить в моделях (используя переопределение метода `clean`, встроенные и самописные валидаторы для полей модели).

Считаю, что это разумно - данные всегда будут верны, независимо от того, откуда и как была создана модель - из `view`, из самописного скрипта и т.п. - неважно вообще.

Но, например, Django не вызывает по какой-то причине метод `.clean()` перед `.save()`.

Cчитаете ли вы хорошей практикой переопределять метод `save()` у модели, добавляя вызов `full_clean()` принудительно? Что вообще думаете по этому поводу? Или меня не туда понесло и я усложняю себе жизнь?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. А я вот не пользуюсь валидаторами, хотя и надо бы. Я думаю, что вызывать full_clean() - это хорошая практика. Тем более, что в вызове можно обработать возникающие ошибки, при проверке. Но конечно это не так удобно как назначать геттеры и сеттеры.